# Xamarin.Forms Pattern image repeat to fill the background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a simple question: in Xamarin Forms is possible to set a image to fill the background of the page?
This is my ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Facedoor" 
         x:Class="Facedoor.LoginPage"
         BackgroundImage="pattern-background.png">
```

The image is a small texture, and I would like to fill the background to repeat it. Is possible?

Comment: For android you can use "`android:tileMode="repeat"` ", but a tiled background  for the 3 platforms using contentpages .... I think you will need a custom renderer.  
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Check this thread, maybe you can do "the same" but resizing your image 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22440/gradient-as-background-color